# Evaluate h(x) = x + 1/x

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Given
$$
h(x) = x + 1/x
$$
Find
$$
h(a-1)
$$
My answer is $0$, since when I put them in fraction form everything cancelled out.

Comment: What do you mean by $h = (a-1)$? Do you mean $h(x)=(a-1)$ and we're trying to find for what $x$ this holds true?

Comment: I mean if h(x) = x + 1/x, find h(a-1)

Comment: Add your own 'I put them in fraction form' to this question to make things more clear.

Comment: Please clarify whether you mean $h(x) = (x+1)/x$ or $h(x) = x + \frac{1}{x}$.

Answer (score 6):

Well indeed we can see
$$
h(a-1) = (a-1) + \frac{1}{a-1} = \frac{(a-1)^2}{a-1} + \frac{1}{a-1} = \frac{a^2 -2a + 1 + 1}{a-1} = \frac{a^2 - 2a + 2}{a-1}
$$
which is well defined for any $a \neq 1$.

EDIT: Just saw in a comment that the function might actually be defined as $h(x) = \frac{x+1}{x}$ as opposed to how I thought it was. If that's the case then
$$
h(a-1) = \frac{a-1+1}{a-1} = \frac{a}{a-1}
$$
which is also well defined for any $a \neq 1$.